# Points of inflexion at circular points at infinity.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, plane-curves

According to the Wikipedia article on Cassini Ovals, a Cassini oval has double-points, which are also inflexion points, at circular points I and J at infinity.  I don't understand how to show that I and J are inflexion points.  Wikipedia references a very old text by Basset which makes the same claim.  Unfortunately, I was not able to find any "computational" support for this statement; only a general discussion about points of contact was given.  I am looking for an explanation or a good reference that I can use to understand this problem.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The Wikipedia article on
[Circular points at infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_points_at_infinity)
gives their homogeneous coordinates as
$$(x_0,y_0,z_0) = (1,\pm i,0). \tag{1}$$
The homogeneous equation for
[Cassini ovals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini_oval) is
$$ P(x,y,z) := (x^2+y^2)^2 - 2 a^2 (x^2-y^2) z^2 + (a^4-b^4) z^4 = 0. \tag{2}$$
Verify for the circular points in equation $(1)$ that
$$ P(x_0,y_0,z_0) = 0. \tag{3}$$

As for [inflection points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection_point), differentiate the equation $(2)$ taking partials to get
the equation of the tangent line at $\,(x_0,y_0,z_0).\,$ Namely,
$$ \frac14 dP(x,y,z) = x((x^2+y^2)-a^2z^2)dx +
y((x^2+y^2)+a^2z^2)dy + z(a^2(y^2-x^2)+(a^4-b^4)z^2)dz.\tag{4}$$
If we evaluate this equation $(4)$ with $\,x^2+y^2=z=0\,$ as
in equation $(1)$ it vanishes which verifies that there
is a double point at infinity.
Also equation $(4)$ is cubic in $\,x,y,z\,$ which verifies that
the circular points are also inflection points of the curve.